# How to locate files in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Something I've really struggled with in Wordpress is how to locate different files. Usually I can trial-and-error until I find it, but this one is really eluding me.

http://mbccs5.wpstagecoach.com/managed-it-service/

^ In the sidebar on the right it says "news." I want to get into the file that has the php in it. This area of the site is going to become a static image that links to a specific page.

Any suggestions for this, and other times this happens?

Thanks!!

Comment: PS. It's not in the widgets area. So far as I can tell, knows this as dynamic_sidebar or sidebar-3.

Comment: Here's a line that I believe is calling it:
if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-3') ) :